# PHP Array as JavaScript - accessing the JavaScript elements by key?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a PHP array, like that:

```
$myArray = array('key1' => value1, 'key2' => value2);
```

I am converting it to JSON using this code:

```
$js = json_encode($myArray);
```

Now in my JavaScript code I want to access the JS array (object?) by its keys, key1 for example, but it doesnt work, the result is always undefined.

Thanks!

Comment: for(var i in json) console.log(json[i]);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
var json = 'yourjsonstring',//'{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}'
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
alert(obj.key1);
```

Comment: Jep, thats the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
function parseJSON(jsonString){
  return eval("(" + jsonString + ")");
}

var object = parseJson(StringFromPhp);
```

You can get mykey like:

```
object.key1  // value1
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you parse the JSON. There are different options to do that, but for example:

```
var parsedData = JSON.parse(your_data);
```

And then you access to the key you're looking for. The following is an "associative" way to access to an array (check [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html) out).

```
alert (parsedData.your_key);
```

Good luck!